# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'username' in ..../memberlist.php(876) : eval()'d code on line 6

Tags: php, arrays, vbulletin

I'm trying to get the usernames of the members on my vbulletin forum so I can use the first letter of their name as an avatar.  I tried the normal way and a few others but I've not been successful.  I think it is due to the info being in an array.  This is my code for the first letter.

```
//get the username
$username = $userinfo['username']; 
//strip to get the first letter
$letterUsername['username'] = substr($username, 0, 1); 
//capitalize the first letter 
$letterUsername['username'] = strtoupper($letterUsername['username']); 
//set it as a variable 
$letterUsername = $letterUsername['username'];
```

I get the error in the title when I run this code on the memberlist.php page.  Line 876 is the hook:

```
($hook = vBulletinHook::fetch_hook('memberlist_bit')) ? eval($hook) : false;
```

How can I get the username for all members on the page using the above code?  I don't have much experience with arrays and really need help.  Here is the memberlist.php file: https://pastebin.com/wfgLikJ2

Comment: Is this a ucwords code you have built? What is a typical input and what is the output supposed to be?

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for the reply.  This uses a persons username to generate an avatar based on the first letter of their username.  The output should be a capital letter.

Comment: `eval` cring... eval is evil, that is the saying.  `The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code.`

Comment: that is the way that vbulletin have coded their files, it is not my coding.

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`? What is `$hook`? Print `$hook` and show us what it is, after all according to you this is the code with problems. You probably don't need to use `eval()` here, and you definitively shouldn't.

Comment: @Havenard I am not using eval() as I stated in my previous comment.  This is the default coding in the vbulletin files.  The $hook is the place inside the template structure where the code is placed.

Comment: @John Ok so I take it vBulletin is storing PHP code in the database or something and has to `eval()` it here to make it run, but apparently the code it stored is corrupted. You gotta check the database to see what it stored there (or just print `$hook`) to identify the problem.

Comment: @Havenard that is correct about the database.  Their code works, I am using the above 4 lines to generate an avatar using the users username.

Comment: What version of vB do you use? My guess is that `$username` (or less likely `$letterUsername`) is used within the `memberlist_bit` hook, and vB expects the variable to be an array. You could try to use different names; e.g. `$my_username`.

Comment: @jh1711, vB 4.2.3.  I pasted a link to the file where the hook is on my initial post.  You can see there what is being used.

Comment: @John, I've seen the link, but I couldn't find the version in the file. And I need that to search for the code that is eval'ed. But now I got it.

Comment: The memberlist_bit hook should be empty for a virgin vB4 install. I also checked a few plugins, and only vBSEO modifies it. I really hope you don't use vBSEO, so I can't help. But you could go back to Havenard's suggestion: 'or just print $hook', and amend your question. Maybe somebody will spot something.

Comment: @jh1711, print $hook shows nothing using a plugin on the memberlist_bit hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to get that 1st letter and capitalize it:

```
// I find it easier just to work with arrays, less functions to memorize
// [0] to get 0 index because str_split() converts string to an array
// Remember, functions are evaluated from innermost to outermost  
$letterUserName = strtoupper(str_split($userinfo['username'])[0]);

// or NOT converting to an Array, both work
// [0] here because string characters can be accessed with []
// "Hello"[1] === "e" 
$letterUserName2 = strtoupper($userinfo['username'][0]);
```

I try to keep as much stuff on 1 line as possible otherwise your code will go 
from 200 lines to 400 lines super fast, making it overwhelming.

I tested it and it works ^_^
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Julius.  I'm not too experienced in php but I can usually manage to get what I need but only after a few lines lol.

Comment: Your Welcome :) It can be a little difficult to squeeze everything into 1 line when you first start, nothing wrong with going line by line so you can see how each step happens (:

Comment: @Andreas, I'm just trying to get in the habit of using arrays for everything because Most humans can't memorize the overwhelming amount of PHP functions and endless frameworks' functions. There is almost always an array solution for native string functions.

Comment: Yes but you are creating an array from a string and then using an string function on the first item of the array which happens to be a string. Can't you see how backwards that is? It's like putting the shoes on the hands and getting in the trunk when you are going to drive the car.

Comment: @Andreas I edited my answer to NOT convert to an array, can you not down vote me. That hurts.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `$` character before your variable name here: `$letterUsername = letterUsername['username'];` => `$letterUsername = $letterUsername['username'];`